# Call custom function on click of ionic 2 RC.1 Back button

Tags: ionic2

How can I call a function on click of back button in Ionic 2 from a specific page?

I have the following scenario in my mind. Lets say I navigate like below:

```
PageA --> PageB --> PageC --> PageD
```

Now when I click back button on `PageD` I want to go back to `PageB` instead of `PageC`. I want to call below function on click of back button.

```
goBack(){
    this.navCtrl.popTo(PageB);
}
```

I have done it Like this:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.bindMethodToElement('back-button',this.goBack);
}

bindMethodToElement(elementClassName,functionToBind){
    try{
      let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClassName);
      let currentElement : Element = elements[elements.length - 1];
      currentElement.addEventListener("click",functionToBind);
    }catch(exception){
      console.log(exception.message);
      throw exception;
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know better approach to do it. I also want to achieve similar behavior when user clicks on the device back button.

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature was already reported to the Ionic team and they are validating it. In the meantime you can use this workaround:

```
goBack(){
  this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => {this.navCtrl.pop()});
}
```

Ugly solution but works. Good luck!